# Store this iteration in .each function

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to build a youtube script..

I have almost got it working properly, but my src url for the video is always referencing the last iteration.. i don't know how to get it to store this iteration, which would be correct.

Here is what i have:

Jquery:

```
$('.tubeWrapper').each(function() {
var tubeurl = $(".dooTubeUrl",this).text();
var thumb = $.jYoutube(tubeurl , 'small');
$(".dooTube_ThumbLink",this).append("<img src=' " + thumb + " ' />");

var url = tubeurl;
$result = getList(url, "v");
// It is this next line that seems to be the problem, allways references the last iteration as expected, but wrong.
$(".youtube-player",this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $result);
});


$('.dooTube_ThumbLink').click(function() {
$(".dooTubeWindow").doo_lightbox();
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="tubeWrapper">
<div class="dooTubeUrl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aA3dHi_o7Yw&feature=related</div>

<div class="dooTube_ThumbLink"><div class="dooTube_Arrow"></div></div>
<div class="dooTubeWindow">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" 
class="youtube-player" 
type="text/html" 
width="480" height="390"
src="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div> 

</div>

<div class="tubeWrapper">
<div class="dooTubeUrl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xvj4Ud-RKrM&feature=related</div>

<div class="dooTube_ThumbLink"><div class="dooTube_Arrow"></div></div>
<div class="dooTubeWindow">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" 
class="youtube-player" 
type="text/html" 
width="480" height="390"
src="" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</div> 

</div>
```

Comment: What does your getList function look like?  Possibly a bug in there as your tubeurl value is fine.

Comment: Hi dave, the getList function just gets the youtube video id from the url. Tested and correct. It will happily play the video that is last in the list, in the class=dooTubeUrl but always the last occurance in the html of class=tubeWrapper. A clue i still cant get my head round is: if i click the link again while the video is loading i get the correct video..! but not the way it should work really..

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger? I'd make sure that $(".youtube-player",this) always gives you what you expect. Also maybe print out the value of $result so you can watch it change on every iteration. This sort of problem should be very easy to solve with some methodical debugging.

Comment: What it is doing is loading both videos into the lightbox, thats called with the click function. i can see now that the last video is simply masking the first/others. So i probably want those .each functions inside the click function... but i dont know how to implement that..

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing var before $result:

```
var $result = ...
```